# Vagrant public network not reachable?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine

I'm trying to using vagrant for a distributed project on my Home Network. This is the Vagrantfile that I'm using on each host (3 machines in total):

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# # vi: set ft=ruby :

# Specify minimum Vagrant version and Vagrant API version
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

# Require YAML module
require 'yaml'

# Read YAML file with box details
servers = YAML.load_file('RaftFS/servers.yaml')

# Create boxes
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
# Create servers
  # Iterate through entries in YAML file
  servers.each do |key,value|
    #the line below will be different on each machine
    if key == "hal9000"
        config.vm.define key do |srv|
            srv.vm.box = value['box']
                #srv.vm.network "private_network", ip: value['ip']
            srv.vm.network :public_network, ip:value['ip']
            srv.vm.hostname=key
            srv.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant" , disabled:true
            srv.vm.synced_folder "ServersFS/"+key+"/", "/vagrant/ServersFS" , create: true
            srv.vm.synced_folder "./RaftFS", "/vagrant/RaftFS"
            srv.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
              shell.path = "provision.sh"
              shell.args = "'TRUE'"
            end
            srv.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
                vb.name = key
                vb.memory = value['ram']
                end
        end
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the `servers.yaml:`

```
jarvis:
     box: hashicorp/precise32
     ram: 512
     ip: 192.168.1.200
     ftpPort: 8080
     diskSpace: 500
skynet:
     box: hashicorp/precise32
     ram: 512
     ip: 192.168.1.201
     ftpPort: 8081
     diskSpace: 500
hal9000:
     box: hashicorp/precise32
     ram: 512
     ip: 192.168.1.202
     ftpPort: 8083   
     diskSpace: 500
```

Now, if I `ssh` each machine and run `ifconfig` the IP is set correctly. The problem is that if I try contact it in any way it semms to be unreachable, even from the same host machine! In other words, trying to `ping` the IP address from the shell of the host machine, no response comes from the guest machine.

Comment: The host normally means the main box that the virtual machine is running on. So if I have a Windows7 laptop with 3 VMs running Ubuntu then I would say that I have a single Windows7 host with 3 VMs/guests running on it so I'm a little unsure what you mean by your last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're only setting the `hal9000` VM to use a public (or bridged) network (or in fact do any configuration) so the other guests are just using the default host only network which should mean that they only have connection to the host machine and not to each other.

If you take out the:

```
if key == "hal9000"
```

line then it should configure things properly.

However, unless you genuinely want the machines to be web facing these VMs should all be in a private network which should work by uncommenting the private networking line you already have there.

Comment: If I set the network as private, it's not pingable (so I deduce visible) from the rest of the network, only by the local host. However, looking the vagrant section about private vs public network there is a lot of confusion and I think that the answer is not unique